# Pequeno bug visual na página meu usuário

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Isso não é um grande *bug* ou algo que atrapalhe a utilização do site. Mas, na página **meu usuário** (não tenho certeza se é assim que se chama), quando se troca a visualização de **acompanhar meu próximo privilégio** para **acompanhar uma medalha de tag**, tem um *bugzinho* visual, a linha está passando por cima da palavra *tag*.

Não é nada demais, mas talvez incomode o pessoal que tem [TOC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtorno_obsessivo-compulsivo), rs.

[image]